# Why a value which was not nill, after a line becomes nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-2.5

I transformed a Rails API application to a normal Rails application, without problem. Then it started giving me some problem, before with the same code it was working perfectly.

I have a Telegram bot and Telegram sends the POST request to my Rails app. So, I have this code to transform the params in an hash:

```
message = params[:message].to_unsafe_h
```

I started logging so I do:

```
logger.debug message.to_yaml
logger.debug message[:text]
```

And it returns correctly

```
D, [2019-08-11T15:39:14.955103 #13713] DEBUG -- : [56fbc12a-ad66-46d6-956d-94870d3ca0ec] --- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
update_id: 200421708
edited_message: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
message_id: 37769
from: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  id: 85039287
  is_bot: false
  first_name: Dennis
  last_name: Radaelli
  username: Radden
chat: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  id: -1001447558052
  title: WIKINETWORK OT - FERDINANDO PADANIA VI FANNO IMPAZZIRE
  type: supergroup
date: 1565477411
edit_date: 1565477416
text: Vada! Vada!
 D, [2019-08-11T15:39:15 #13714] DEBUG -- : Vada! Vada!
```

But, if I do `if message[:text] =~ /asd/i`, it returns me `No method error, undefined method [] for Nil:NilClass`. But it isn't nil! It said that correctly a few seconds ago.

This is insane. I've spent 3 hours testing and I didn't understand why. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Sorry for such a dumb question, but what is `=~ /asd/i`? Perhaps the error is resulting during the processing of that call and not because `message[:text]` is nil.

Comment: @jvillian It's a regex test, it doesn't cause this error.

Comment: Seeing your unclosed `if` statement makes me feel like we're not seeing all the context needed to answer this question. What does `puts (logger.debug message[:text] =~ /asd/i)` or `logger.debug (message[:text] =~ /asd/i)` return? How does the rest of the conditional statement look?